# how to make it as one?

Tags: mysql

```
rechargedate |   mobile       |   amount
-------------+----------------+--------
01-07-2009   |   0103001199   |   50.00
01-07-2009   |   0103001199   |   50.00
20-07-2009   |   0103001199   |   50.00
```

Above is a part of my data, now I want to make recharges of the same number on the same day become one row:

```
rechargedate  |  mobile       |  Amount
--------------+---------------+--------
01-07-2009    |  0103001199   |  50.00
20-07-2009    |  0103001199   |  20.00
```

How can I do that (convert? cast?)?

Comment: Should the row dropped or do you need a sum?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your question, and make it more readable?

Comment: SELECT a.rechargedate, a.mobileno,sum(a.Amount),b.reg_dealer, (c.agn_code + '-' + c.agn_master_code + '-' + c.agn_state + '-' + c.agn_dealer_code), b.reg_activationdate from recharge a, dailyregistration b, agents c where substring(b.reg_dealer, 5, 6) = c.agn_dealer_code and b.reg_id = a.mobileno and month(a.rechargedate) = 7 group by a.rechargedate, a.mobileno, b.reg_dealer, (c.agn_code + '-' + c.agn_master_code + '-' + c.agn_state + '-' + c.agn_dealer_code), b.reg_activationdate order by a.mobileno

Comment: this are the sql statement i had done.
but i had to make the data bcum one as 01-07-2009 got appear twice, rite? so i had to join the same date as one.. 
cum out one time onli

Comment: SELECT cast(convert(varchar, a.rechargedate, 112) as datetime)as rechargedate, a.mobileno, 
(c.agn_code + '-' + c.agn_master_code + '-' + c.agn_state + '-' + c.agn_dealer_code)as reg_dealer, b.reg_prod_agent, b.reg_activationdate,sum(a.Amount) as Amount
from recharge a, dailyregistration b, agents c
where 
substring(b.reg_dealer, 5, 6) = c.agn_dealer_code
and b.reg_id = a.mobileno...............


anywhere, thanks everyone. i had found my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM table GROUP BY columns
```

looks like you'll be needing GROUP BY as well

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT *columns* FROM *table* WHERE .....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [distinct](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqldistinct.html)?

Answer (score 1):

If the two rows are identical, you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword right after `SELECT`:

```
select DISTINCT rechargedate, mobile, amount FROM yourTable
```

This will not work if you have rows such as:

```
rechargedate |   mobile       |   amount
-------------+----------------+--------
01-07-2009   |   0103001199   |  150.00
01-07-2009   |   0103001199   |   50.00
20-07-2009   |   0103001199   |   50.00
```

In that case you need to `GROUP BY` the rechargedate. This will fetch only one row for each different rechargedate, which might not always be what you need:

```
select rechargedate, mobile, amount FROM yourTable GROUP BY rechargedate
```

Comment: I think you mean "Group by rechargedate, mobile". Also, you'll probably want to SUM(amount)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rechargedate, mobile, SUM(amount) FROM tablename
GROUP BY rechargedate, mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.rechargedate, a.mobileno,sum(a.Amount),b.reg_dealer, 
(c.agn_code + '-' + c.agn_master_code + '-' + c.agn_state + '-' + c.agn_dealer_code), b.reg_activationdate
from recharge a, dailyregistration b, agents c
where 
substring(b.reg_dealer, 5, 6) = c.agn_dealer_code
and b.reg_id = a.mobileno
and month(a.rechargedate) = 7
group by a.rechargedate, a.mobileno, b.reg_dealer, (c.agn_code + '-' + c.agn_master_code + '-' + c.agn_state + '-' + c.agn_dealer_code), b.reg_activationdate
order by a.mobileno
```

Comment: That is one hard to read query. I recommend using ANSI joins http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 instead and that you investigate if you possibly could normalize your database so that the substring matching isn't needed. I also recommend that you read http://stackoverflow.com/faq to learn when to answer, comment, vote up/down and so on.